# Surfaceview/ Camera Preview on Galaxy S4 displays Green and Tiles

Tags: android, camera, surfaceview

```
[screenshot](https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-j3qMl6-nYfo/UmDVYIl3wLI/AAAAAAAAAD8/Qa3M_z-6bAs/s720/Screenshot_2013-10-18-14-20-51.png)
```

here is my code. Im also having problems with my camera rotate function it causes app to crash but this is limited only to s4 devices. Thanks in advance guys.

http://titanpad.com/hdtu6b0V4J